# How to get the desktop to show on a debian 10 machine that's configured to hide it?

Tags: linux, debian

I have no idea of how the machine was configured. When turning it on it runs a version of Firefox set to a local website.

Where could I start to look at how the configuration might have been changed? And any ideas of how to restore the desktop?

I know my way around some linux distributions but nothing as advanced as this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a login you could try `Ctrl + Alt +F2` (or any other function keys). This should throw you into a tty session where you can login (you need root access for some the following steps) and type in some coommands.

Under Linux it is possible to run some programs without a [Desktop Enironment](https://wiki.debian.org/DesktopEnvironment). If you want to install a desktop environment afterwards you should first try to disable the autostart behavior of Firefox. My guess is, that it starts as an service.

Try typing `systemctl list-units --type=service` as root and look for anything that looks like it could be firefox. To disable  a service type `systemctl disable "ServiceName"`.

The service shouldn't launch at a reboot now (therefore firefox aswell). Now you have to install a desktop environment. There are a lot of them. [Here](https://linuxhint.com/install_gnome_debian_10_minimal_server/)  is a guide how to install Gnome on Debian server which by default has no desktop environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it out. :)